# Conditional SUM in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

Let's say I have the following table:

Table 1:

[image: table1]

Let's say there is another table: Table2:

[image: table2]

How do I sum the value of the `Count` column of `Table 1` into `Table 2` in PowerBI for A, B, C, or any n number of names that might exist?

It is a simple `=SUMIF()` function in Excel. Not sure about PowerBI

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI you need to shift your mindset. You don't create a formula like Sumif(). You can create a measure to sum the column, or you can rely on the built-in automatic measures.

If you want to see the data in a table, pull a table onto the canvas and drop the fields into the field wells. The calculation will be automatic. No formulas.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up

Comment: Hi Teylyn,

I see what you did there. Perhaps let me extend further what kind of problem I am dealing with.

Like a, b, c from this example, I have 1000 different names each occurring multiple times and add up to 15k records in Table 1.

And in Table 2, about 520 of the 1000 available names are present(this is a given table for me, I don't choose those 520 records) and about 200 new names appear here(which is fine cos there are some more fields in this table).

I want to get the sum of each of the 520 names and for the extra 200, I want to get the sum as 0. Can you help with this?